# Transforming an wp_options database array into a javascript obect?

Tags: database, javascript

In my WP code I grab my options information as such `$options = get_option("kaipo_plugin_options");`

The array that I print out looks as follows

```
a:2:{s:20:"Kaipo_banner_heading";s:5:"hello";s:10:"Kaipo_logo";s:61:"http://nzbaddystore.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/images.jpg";}
```

I want to transform this array into a javascript object dynamically? any suggestions? that way I can simply choose specific data from my array and print it out for the users to see. for example `$options['kaipo_banner_heading'];`

Comment: Your data should already be unserialized - currently it's still a string. How are you saving your options?

Comment: using add_option

Comment: Is there a way I can transform that array into a much simpler javascript object to work with on the front end? fr example if I wanted to just grab the email link

Answer (score 0):

It seems like that your result is not being unserialized.
try:

```
$options = get_option("kaipo_plugin_options");
$unserialized_options = maybe_unserialize($options);
print_r($unserialized_options, true);
```